# Reuseable Components / Directives ng2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a navigation component like so :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

const template = require('./navigation.jade');
const styles = require('./navigation.sass');

@Component({
    selector: 'navigation',
    templateUrl: template,
    styleUrls: [styles]
})

export class NavComponent {

 }
```

Rather than manually add it to the head of every page, I'd like to include this in my `app.component.ts` file.

Currently I am achieving this as follows :

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {NavComponent} from './components/navigation/navigation.component';

const styles = require('./base-styles.sass');

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavComponent],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [styles],
    template: `
    <navigation></navigation>
    <div class="container">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

However importing a `Component` and then including this as a `Directive` selector feels wrong, I'm sure this is not correct, how best can I achieve this?

If I try to convert this to a directive, I am not able to require in a template file and import my navigation bar into the DOM.

I'm new to ng and keen to learn only the best practice, this may work, however it feels a little 'hacky...'

Comment: That's exactly how you do it. With the next update modules will be introduced where you can provide it for an entire module. Otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986768/angular-2-rc1-auto-import-all-used-components-inside-a-base-component/37986944#37986944 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897005/angular-2-0-0-rc-2-how-to-migrate-platform-directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide directives globally

```
provide({provide: PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, useValue: [NavComponent], multi: true})
```

but in general the way you do it is the preferred way.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As usual Gunter is correct with his comment :) importing and using as a directive is the correct way (if you wish for nav to be its own component). Also if you interested all the angular best practices the [angular.io](https://angular.io/) is the place to go.